# Associate a certificate with a https url

Tags: java, ssl, certificate

I want to connect to https://twitter.com/,

```
URL url = new URL("https://twitter.com/");
HttpURLConnection uc1 = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

I verified location of my truststore and my keystore (and their password), it's ok.
I saved twitter certificate and alias on keystore and truststore. I verified, it's in.

I don't know how to link url with the certificate I saved; I get the error :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

How I do that ?

******UPDATE********

I set truststore and keystore with setProperty already.
When I do keytool -list -keystore .keystore on console, I get

...

twittercert, 2 févr. 2017, trustedCertEntry,
Empreinte du certificat (SHA1) : 10:F0:40:F2:93:7F:E0:69:2D:C1:B9:8C:8B:32:CC:E0:1E:43:82:52

...

The same with keytool -list

Answer (score 0):

Twitter certificate is issued by DigiCert that is included as trusted root in the default truststore of JVM, so you would not need to configure anything.

If you have configured your own JKS truststore, probably is misconfigured. Ensure you have set the correct path to your truststore using `System.setProperty` or `-D` VM parameter.

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStorePath); 
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustStorePassword)
```

Verify also that truststore contains the *root* certificate of Digicert

**Updated**
Note that the SHA-1 fingerprint of the twitter certificate you have posted is not equal than the extracted today. May be you have an old copy?

[image]

Avoid this importing into truststore the root CA instead of the leaf certificate

Comment: @ehcnalb, could you check the answer?